# How to use R to select the same column from every element in a list into one column

Tags: r

`dfs` is a list whose element is a data frame containing information of environment in a city.
And I want to get `PM_US.Post` of each city in one column.

I've tried: `PM_2.5 <- sapply(dfs,`[[`,"PM_US.Post")`

What I've got is each column represents one city's `PM_US.Post`:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyBKY.jpg)

But I want to get them in one column.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(dfs, `[`, 'PM_US.Post'))
```

Or with `purrr`

```
purrr::map_df(list_df, `[`, 'PM_US.Post')
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 11:15, c = 16:20)
dfs <- list(df1, df2)

do.call(rbind, lapply(dfs, `[`, 'a'))
#    a
#1   1
#2   2
#3   3
#4   4
#5   5
#6  11
#7  12
#8  13
#9  14
#10 15
```